# Install apk on multiple android devices

Tags: android, installation, apk

I need to install an application in about 500 tablets with android.
Is there any way to do this automatically without me having to manually install on each device.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without configuting every device at the beginning. I have already installed an app on 13 devices. I know how painful that is... I could imagine that the connection of the device can be detected automatically but the installation process required a change of the default settings of that device.

Answer (score 0):

post the apk on a web server..access that page via the tablet and install the app...
i personally don't think there is any other way...there must be some sort of action on the device to install the app

Comment: I'm thinking in some alternatives, but all of then have some manual step.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through adb, put you apk file on a SD card or something or a given url and then through command prompt use

```
adb install <1>/<2>.apk
```

where `<1>` is path of the apk and `<2>` is the name of apk.

although its manual, but still be fast enough as you send a command and connect another tablet.

Comment: It's possible to configure the same google acount on multiple devices?
I'm thinking in do that and put the app on market. That way android will keep the app updated automaticly.

Comment: yes that's possible. but initial install will be much faster doing ir through adb or writing an app that does market setup and install app for you too.

Comment: @user1299266 if you want to use the google account you have also to set it on the device, so far you have to configurate every device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have to reinstall the app over and over again you could always create another application to handle all this.  Sometimes a reinstall will fail so you will have to uninstall first.  This app could also check a web server once a day to see if your main application needs to be updated.